# iOS - Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application

Tags: ios, orientation

Just wondering if anyone has run into this issue before. I'm recently getting this error:

Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and [_UIAlertShimPresentingViewController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES

This seems to only be happening when I bring an alertview to the screen.

Comment: Is it for all alerts? Or just specific ones?

Comment: All alerts. I figured out the issue. Its related to UIAlertViews being deprecated in iOS 8